# Cancan blocks vs conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I've got the following code block in my Abilities.rb:

```
  can :read, Comment do |comment|
    comment.user.account == user.account
  end
```

I'm trying to convert it a statement (of the form:

```
can :read, Project, :active => true, :user_id => user.id
```

so that I can use the `accessible_by` methods.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is an account_id field in your user model, you can cross associations in cancan conditions like this:

```
can :read, Comment, { :user => { :account_id => user.account.id } }
```

Comment: I tried this, but I found that accessible_by still didn't work; I expected that when calling the index action, I would see only the records to which I had access to, as this @comments = Comment.accessible_by(current_ability) should be automatic?

Comment: yes, it should work automatically. You don't need the outer hash though, that was a mistake. maybe like this: ` can :read, Comment, :user => { :account_id => user.account.id }`